# MACROs internal working

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MUL( a, b) a##b
int main(  )
{
    //static int a = 5;
  //  while( --a )
  printf("%d",MUL(2+3,4+5));
    //{
      //  printf("%d ",a);
//        main(10);
    //}

    return 0;
}

OUTPUT: 41
```

why the output of the program is 41?
I am using token pasting operator that should merge the two numbers.
I am expecting the output as 59 but its showing 41.

Comment: please ignore the comments.and the output is 41.sorry for the wrong output.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. You can edit your question at any time. Use this rather than making correction in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

After replacement it will look like

```
printf("%d", 2+34+5) );  // 2+34+5 = 41
```

<strike>It will never print `28`.</strike>

The argument to `MUL` will not evaluate before the replacement.

Answer (score 1):

When a macro is expanded, the two tokens on either side of each ‘##’ operator are combined into a single token. Expressions are not evaluated and passed to the macro.

In this case the expansion would be `2+3 ## 4+5 i.e 2 + 34 + 5 = 41`.

Answer (score 0):

```
MUL(2+3,4+5)
```

will expand to

```
 2+3##4+5
```

which is

```
2+34+5
```

It evaluates to 41.

To get 59, you need to call `MUL(5,9)`. For even `MUL((2+3),(4+5))`, preprocessing will be done first which will make it to

`(2+3)(4+5)`

and will result in compiler error.

MACROs are replaced before compilation phase.